# Immediate Window without debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, rapid-prototyping

Rapid prototyping is arguably one of the most efficient ways to test new designs and I believe this to hold true for programming too.

I am looking for a tool similar to Matlab where one can execute some C# code while you type. The Immediate Window is almost ideal, but is naturally only usable when debugging.

Is there a way to use the Immediate Window (or a similar tool) without having to switch into debugging mode?

**UPDATE:**

After some more googling I found:

- [C# Shell](http://blog.schmichael.com/2006/12/20/cssh-c-shell/) (cssh): A cool idea, but quite limited at this stage.
- [SnippetCompiler](http://www.sliver.com/dotnet/SnippetCompiler/): Nice, but I would prefer a command line type behaviour where the command is execute once I hit *return*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try LinqPad, it rocks !  It is made to test Linq queries but it ends being the best environment to try any kind of C# code ever made.

http://www.linqpad.net/

It is free but need to be activated (paid) to support intellisense.

Comment: btw, it also support VB and F# ! Being so enthusiast and advertising, I think I deserve a free license :-)

Comment: Perfect! (Now they just need to integrate it in VS)

Comment: The intellisense works very well. Definitely worth paying for a license.

Comment: Is there an online tool anywhere? I can't find an online immediate window.

Comment: @toddmo there is https://dotnetfiddle.net/ which provides a .NET console, .NET scripting and even MVC (C#, VB.NET and F#).